# What is the difference if I put media="screen" and not

Tags: css, media-queries

I have seen lots of websites importing css like

```
<link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

and some has

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

I really wonder what does it makes the difference if we put **media="screen"** attribute the link element.

Comment: well, if you print out that page, the `screen` style sheet won't be applied...

Comment: It excludes printing layout. In other words, that’s the styling for screen devices only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That stylesheet creates the styles for a printed version of the site, if you wanted a change in look when printed.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple reasons:

1. **Most Important**, when you print the page, the `screen` styles appear too.
2. You can define the styles just for one particular media.
3. Screen readers can have a different CSS media `aural` (deprecated) or `speech`.

Check [Using Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

It's a media query.  This one in particular only uses that style sheet when viewed on a traditional screen (ie not a screen reader). [More info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Media queries determine when the styles should apply. It depends on what device or medium the user is viewing your content on.

Answer (score 0):

Media type screen tells that the style.css should load only in case of screens like computer-screens, tablets, smart-phones, etc. The css will not load for print-preview or screen-readers.